# License required for x-webkit-speech API or Npt?

Tags: html, webspeech-api

I want to integrate voice search via x-webkit-speech API of google in my website.voice Search will be used by Public on website.Do i need a license from Google for it? Where can i see terms and conditions for use of this API?

Comment: Apparently, the API name is "WebSpeech API" rather than "x-webkit-speech API".